# Django select_related filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following Django models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    tmp = models.ForeignKey(B)
    active = models.BooleanField()

class B(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
    archived = models.BooleanField()
```

Now I have the following query.

```
A.objects.select_related(B).filter(active=True)
```

Now this fetches all the objects of B. Now how can I include a filter of `active=True` and `archived=False` in the `select_related` clause for model `B`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The same as you would with any other related field, with a `__` lookup..

```
A.objects.select_related(B).filter(active=True, tmp__active=True, tmp__archived=False)
```

Using select related doesn't change anything here, its purpose is about what information is returned with the results, it has no effect on filtering at all.

Comment: But do I need that `select_related` for this? Can I not just use the filter on B with `__`

Comment: why using selecte_related then ?