# Using join of temporary table as an alternative of `IN` in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

In Django it's common to do the following

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=[huge array])
```

However it's not very efficient as described in the following answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in

What would be a good way of replicating the above answer in Django given that you are using the ORM. Or would you have to drop down to raw sql for the entire query.

What I'm looking for is if you have a queryset, is there a good way of joining that queryset with a temporary table that you created (possibly in raw sql).

Comment: Most likely the fastest operation would be to put the IDs into a table, index the column, and do an exists check against MyModel.

Comment: How was the `[huge array]` populated?

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: How `[huge array]` is populated is not very relevant. Just assume that it exists from the start, the time it takes to populate it is not part of the consideration. 

I'm more interested in the approach described in the answer that is being linked if there is a good way of translating that to using models in django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select_related option, to filter your second table(another model) that will do the `in` effect.

Something like this answer: [Django select_related filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926898/django-select-related-filter)

I use that for large `IN`s when its possible.

Answer (score 0):

django-model-utils package provides a similar functionality via the [`JoinManager`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.1/managers.html#joinmanager).

Unfortunately it requires that the `huge_array` of IDs is also provided as a queryset. If that doesn't work, you can take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/blob/4.1.1/model_utils/managers.py#L307) and try to adjust it to your own use case.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share how you are generating the "huge array", but if it can be generated using a simple ORM query of some kind, then your problem is easy to solve.  Django will automatically make this into one query for you and send it to the DB as a nested `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (SELECT ....)`.  From there, you can let the DB do what it does best. Don't worry about trying to create a temporary table of IDs, etc.

So, first build your huge array but leave it as a Django Queryset, eg:

`huge_array = SomeOtherModel.filter(start_date__lt='1999-01-01')`

In some cases, you may need to explicitly indicate which field from `SomeOtherModel` holds the ID, but I think you don't have to do that if there's already an established FK relationship.  But, I usually add this:

`huge_array = huge_array.values_list('the_id_field', flat=True)`

After this, you now have huge_array as a QuerySet, which means Django can embed the whole query into other queries.  Going back to your original problem, now if you write:

`MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=huge_array)`

The whole thing will be sent as a nested SQL query and will all be quite efficient.  No worries about how "huge" the huge array is.

(Well... you might need to do some troubleshooting on the db side if this really is huge... But it won't really be a standar